# prestashop, conflict with two modules

Tags: debugging, prestashop

I use two modules called "expeditor inet" and "Livechatpro" on my e-shop.
The first help me to send packages and the second to discuss with buyers.

When i activate the second, the first module doesn't work.

I am not a prestashop expert, someone can help me to find a way to debug those two modules.

What is the first step to find a solution ?

i have an error :

"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://xxxx.com/admin/index.php?controller=AdminExpeditor&token=xxxxxxx"

Comment: You should try setting `_PS_MODE_DEV_` to `true` to see the error.

Comment: Thanks you , very useful !